# AngularJS array filter not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, multidimensional-array

How can I make the this filter work?

```
<div ng-repeat="rvs in reviews | filter:{ Name:'{{ r.Name }}' }">
 {{ rvs.Name }}
</div>
```

'r.Name' comes from other array "r in restaurants"

However, instead of r.Name directly putting the string works, like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="rvs in reviews | filter:{ Name:'John' }">
 {{ rvs.Name }}
</div>
```

Array Files

'reviews'

```
{
  "reviews": [
    {
      "Name": "Sagar Ratna",
      "Reviewer": "Jaskaran",
      "Comments": "Great service, healthy food!",
      "Date": "25th Sept. 2016",
      "Rating" : "4"
    },
    {
      "Name": "The Night Factory",
      "Reviewer": "Pawandeep",
      "Comments": "Nice location, ok service!",
      "Date": "29th Sept. 2016",
      "Rating" : "3"
    }
  ]
}
```

Restaurants

```
{
  "records": [
    {
      "Name": "Sagar Ratna",
      "Image": "./images/sr.jpg",
      "Address": "Mohali",
      "Type": "South Indian",
      "Hours" : "10:00-23:30"
    },
    {
      "Name": "The Night Factory",
      "Image": "./images/nf.jpg",
      "Address": "Chandigarh",
      "Type": "South Indian",
      "Hours" : "24/7"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you place here your both array reviews and r ??

Comment: When you are inside angular tag, you don't need to use mustaches {{}}. Try only `filter:{ Name:' r.Name '}`

Comment: @VaibhavPatil updated!

Comment: @LucasCosta no success!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `'{{}}'` from `'{{r.Name}}'`

```
<div ng-repeat="rvs in reviews | filter:{ Name:  r.Name  }">
 {{ rvs.Name }}
</div>
```